# how to edit sys.executable permanently in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to install py2cairo but I am getting the following error:

```
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : ok 
Checking for program python              : /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python 
python executable '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python' different from sys.executable '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7'
Checking for python version              : (2, 7, 9, 'final', 0)
```

The output of `which python` is:

```
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python
```

and `sys.executable` is:

```
'/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7'
```

So i wanted to know how to make both of them same.

I am using MAC, not sure if it makes any difference though.

Comment: You really don't want to fix `sys.executable`, you want to [fix pycairo's installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232529/how-to-install-pycairo-for-python-3-on-ubuntu-10-04). pycairo has trouble with the symlink `python` pointing to the real binary. `export PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7` seems to help.

Comment: @dhke Thanks. This worked for me.